# GNU plot: How to plot a sphere and imported file on the same frame?

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I am very new to GNU plot. Now, I am trying to plot a sphere and imported `.txt` file at the **same frame**. However, I cannot figure out a suitable way. Here are my attempts:

1. **Using only** `splot`.

   `set parametric ; unset pm3d ; splot [-pi:pi] [-pi/2:pi/2] cos(u)*cos(v), cos(u)*sin(v), sin(u) ; unset parametric ; splot "traj_3dtest.txt" u 2:3:4`

   But there is only `splot "traj_3dtest.txt" u 2:3:4` in output file.
2. **Using** `multiplot`

   `set parametric
    splot cos(u)*cos(v), cos(u)*sin(v), sin(u)
    splot "traj_3dtest.txt" u 2:3:4`

   But the output shows that overlapped two plot, [prnt_scrn_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2ww1.png)

Here are also extra question: how to plot the spherical "surface"? I mean, I don't want a sphere with contours but a gray surface.

**NOTE:** the data file format

`#      T          X        Y        Z       Vx       Vy       Vz
      1.00   -0.429   -0.847    0.314   -.09755   -.29510   -.15748
      2.00   -0.429   -0.848    0.314   -.09752   -.29504   -.15750
      3.00   -0.429   -0.848    0.313   -.09749   -.29497   -.15752
      4.00   -0.429   -0.848    0.313   -.09746   -.29491   -.15755`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want both in the same frame, but not overlapping:

```
splot cos(u)*cos(v), cos(u)*sin(v), sin(u), "traj_3dtest.txt" u 2:3:4
```

From your `multiplot` example, you'd have the two plots with separate axis:

```
set multiplot layout 2,1
splot cos(u)*cos(v), cos(u)*sin(v), sin(u)
splot "traj_3dtest.txt" u 2:3:4
```

or

```
set multiplot

set origin 0,0.5
set size 1,0.5
splot cos(u)*cos(v), cos(u)*sin(v), sin(u)

set origin 0,0
set size 1,0.5
splot "traj_3dtest.txt" u 2:3:4
```

Comment: Thanks! What I am looking for is more like the first solution.